# How to update from Crystal to Dashing (OS X)?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there-

I'm not able to find instructions on the wiki for performing updates between ROS2 versions on OS X. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325882/how-to-update-from-crystal-to-dashing-(os-x)?/) by [giantcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/42801/giantcola/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not an "upgrade" specifically. You'll just want to install dashing. https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/

You can choose to remove and replace your crystal install, or install dashing in a parallel directory and use it there.

If you're looking for what's changed and tips for porting your code there's an overview here:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Dashing-Diademata/#changes-since-the-crystal-release

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [giantcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/42801/giantcola/) on 2019-11-09**:
Thank you!